# Find new Polygon Coordinates when I already have Old Image Size New Image Size and polygon Coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, math

I want to resize a polygon when I already have it's old coordinate as [(100,200),(200,300),(300,400),(50,60),(90,100),(400,300)] and old Image size is 1980x1080 and new image size is 640x480. How can I get new Coordinates of Polygon?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Multiply the x-coordinates by 640/1980 and the y-coordinates by 480/1080.

Comment: The information you provided are not enough to uniquely identify a transformation of the plane which can be used to compute how a set of points map into another. However, if you assume that the origins of the old and the new planes do coincide, and that the transformation is a scaling, then the scaling factors can be computed as mentioned by @Stef.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the x-coordinates by 640/1980 and the y-coordinates by 480/1080.

Since you tagged `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

old_polygon = np.array([(100,200),(200,300),(300,400),(50,60),(90,100),(400,300)])
new_polygon = old_polygon * (np.array([640, 480]) / np.array([1980, 1080]))
```